# How to cancel a running function through a variable=false condition in tkinter canvas action

Tags: python, function, if-statement, canvas, tkinter

Im trying to stop well-working drawing function through a stop button. After pressing the start button I can insert rectangles. That's what I want. However, if I activate the stop button (see code below) which set the condition to insert = false, stil can insert rectangles. This should not be the case. What's going wrong?

```
import tkinter as tk

def insert_cells():
    global insert
    def xyposition(event):
        x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        c = cell-1
        x0 = int((x//cell)*cell+1)
        y0 = int((y//cell)*cell+1)
        canvas.create_rectangle(x0,y0,x0+c,y0+c, width=0, fill='green')

    if not(insert):
        return
    else:
        canvas.bind("<Button-1>", xyposition)

def stop_insert_cells():
    global insert
    insert = False

# MAIN
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
n=30
m=30
cell=10
w = n*cell
h = m*cell

# canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width = w, height = h, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.place(x=20, y=20)

# border canvas
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,w-1,h-1, outline = 'black')

# raster canvas
x1 = 1
y1 = 1
x2 = w-2
y2 = h-2
for i in range(1,m): # horizontal lines
    canvas.create_line(x1,i*cell,x2,i*cell)
for i in range(1,n): # vertical lines
    canvas.create_line(i*cell,y1,i*cell,y2)

# cell filling
insert = True

start_insert_button = tk.Button(root, text='start', command = insert_cells)
stop_insert_button = tk.Button(root, text = 'stop', command = stop_insert_cells)

stop_insert_button.pack(side='bottom')
start_insert_button.pack(side='bottom')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because you create the bind when clicking start button but did not unbind when clicking stop button.  So when you click on the canvas, the bind callback will still be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have binded the `<Button-1>` event to a callback when the `start` button is clicked, but do not unbind the callback when the `stop` button is clicked.  So the binded callback will still be called when the canvas is clicked.

Either you unbind the callback (in this case, do not need the global variable `insert`):

```
def insert_cells():
    def xyposition(event):
        x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        c = cell-1
        x0 = int((x//cell)*cell+1)
        y0 = int((y//cell)*cell+1)
        canvas.create_rectangle(x0,y0,x0+c,y0+c, width=0, fill='green')

    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", xyposition)

def stop_insert_cells():
    canvas.unbind('<Button-1>')
```

or bind the callback at program start, then setting global variable `insert` to start or stop the insertion:

```
def xyposition(event):
    if insert:
        x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        c = cell-1
        x0 = int((x//cell)*cell+1)
        y0 = int((y//cell)*cell+1)
        canvas.create_rectangle(x0,y0,x0+c,y0+c, width=0, fill='green')

def insert_cells():
    global insert
    insert = True

def stop_insert_cells():
    global insert
    insert = False

...

# cell filling
insert = False
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', xypostion)
```

Note that your code may create multiple rectangles at the same cell.  Better do some housekeeping to check whether the rectangle at the cell is already created.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I can go on now with my project. And also thanks for your warning to do some house keeping. I did not realize that, Sjaak